# \r\n Not Working in text email coding?

Tags: php, html

I am sending an email which attaches a pdf.

This is the code:

```
 $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
 $content = $mpdf->Output('', 'S');
 $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
 $mailto = $email;
 $from_name = $yourname;
 $from_mail = $fromwho;
 $replyto = $replyto;
 $uid = md5(uniqid(time())); 
 $subject = 'Horse Details';
 $message = 'Please find attached details about the horse medical treatment.';
 $filename = 'Horse';
 $header = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">\r\n";
 $header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
 $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
 $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
 $header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
 $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
 $header .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
 $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
 $header .= $message."\r\n\r\n";
 $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
 $header .= "Content-Type: application/pdf; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n";
 $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
 $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
 $header .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
 $header .= "--".$uid."--";
```

I would like to add more details in the message and use \r\r for new paragraphs etc.

But for some reason the \r\r or \n will not work? Suspect it is because of some of the header info but not sure which one? Had a bit of a play but could not work it out.

Can you see the problem?

Thank you.

Comment: You have various injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: What do you mean "does not work" ?

Comment: According to RFC 2821 you should use `\r\n` in headers.

Comment: When I add \r\r to the message such as 'Please find attached details about the horse medical treatment.\r\rThank you' it actually comes out looking exactly like that rather then having a line/space above Thank you???

Comment: I suspect it is something like one of these that is causing the problem?? $header .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";

Comment: Why are you adding the message body to `$header`, and how are you ultimately submitting the message? I would expect the library to provide means to pass in headers, a textual body, and attachments as parameters or instance attributes.

Answer (score 0):

well i don't seem to get it wrong when i sent it , here's the source of the sent message

> Subject: Horse Details 
>   From: elibyy  Reply-To: test@test.org
>   MIME-Version: 1.0 Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
>   boundary="660d0865650c12fa07c8430814690009"
>
> This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
>   --660d0865650c12fa07c8430814690009 Content-type:text/plain;
>   charset=iso-8859-1 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
>
> Please find attached details about the horse medical treatment.
>
> --660d0865650c12fa07c8430814690009 Content-Type: application/pdf;
>   name="Horse" Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 Content-Disposition:
>   attachment; filename="Horse"
>
> --660d0865650c12fa07c8430814690009--
>
> Please find attached details about the horse medical treatment.

Comment: Did you try adding a \r\r new paragraph??

Comment: If you adds this you will see the issue 
$message = 'Please find attached details about the horse medical treatment.\r\rThank you';